# Не могу загрузить тему на WP?

Tags: wordpress

установил wordpress локально на мак
хочу загрузить тему через плагины
добавляю через плагины-установить новый
и ругается на то что "Ссылка, по которой вы перешли, устарела."

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: WordPress не предназначен для того, что вы делаете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Темы надо устанавливать через установщик тем, а не плагинов!

Comment: так тоже не работает!)

Comment: Тема у вас в zip?

Comment: Да, конечно в zip

Comment: Покажите ваш архив